# jquery pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I have the following code

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div>Pagination one</div>
       <a>Edit</a>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div>Pagination two</div>
       <a>Edit</a>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div>Pagination three</div>
       <a>Edit</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Like this I have 50 div's i.e., 50 records.Is there is any plugin to have the pagination for the above div structure displaying 5 divs in each page.

Answer (score 1):

you may use a [carousel](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin:

[jQuery Pagination](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty simple, but requires that you change those divs to li elements.
http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/

and this one is really fancy but requires a little more putting together.
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-a-jquery-pagination-solution/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if this can help you because this works with a html `table` but I made this example for some project before:

**Take a look:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/Mm9xH/